# $ ROSDISTRO is rolling, although ROS2 Galactic is installed

Tags: ros, setup.bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have recently installed ROS2 Galactic from source with instructions from the tutorials (https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Installation/Ubuntu-Development-Setup.html)

When I open a new terminal, and run `echo $ROS_DISTRO`, the variable is empty as expected.

I source galactic's setup file, `source ~/ros2_galactic/install/setup.bash`, then run `echo $ROS_DISTRO`.

`rolling` is printed out in the terminal, whereas it should be `galactic`, why could this be happening?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/380657/$-rosdistro-is-rolling,-although-ros2-galactic-is-installed/) by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 460 on 2021-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could be because the version of the `ros2.repos` file those instructions have you download points to `master`, which [makes you download the `rolling` branch of `ros_environment`](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/blob/3d98527067e4915933a99b4b7f89a4fbe3039592/ros2.repos#L174-L177).

Not sure why the documentation tells you to do that.

The [Foxy instructions download the `foxy` version of `ros2.repos`](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Installation/Ubuntu-Development-Setup.html#get-ros-2-code).

I'd suggest opening an issue on the [ros2/ros2_documentation](https://github.com/ros2/ros2_documentation/issues) issue tracker. You might even already fix it and submit a PR.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) on 2021-06-19**:
Confirmed that, that is the case. Thanks! I have put a PR up for the fix. (https://github.com/ros2/ros2_documentation/pull/1693)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-06-22**:
@ijnek: I guess this did not solve the problem after all?

**Comment by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) on 2021-06-22**:
@gvdhoorn Apologies, I accidentally unchecked this as the correct answer without realising. Back to correct answer!